# Keras' Resnet finetuning either underfits or overfits: how can I balance the training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, resnet

I'm finetuning Keras' Resnet pre trained on imagenet data to work on a specific classification with another dataset of images. My model is structured as follows: Resnet takes the inputs, and on the top of Resnet I added my own classifier. During all the experiments I tried, the model either underfitted or overfitted.

I mainly tried two approaches:

- block a certain number `n` of layers towards the input, not to let them be updated during the training. In particular, Resnet has 175 layers, and I tried with `n` = 0, 10, 30, 50, 80, 175. In all these cases, the model underfits, obtaining an accuracy over the training set at most equal to 0.75, and on the validation at most 0.51.
- block all the batch normalization layers, plus some `n` layers at the beginning (as before), with `n` = 0, 10, 30, 50. In these cases, the model overfits, obtaining more than 0.95 of accuracy on the training set, but around 0.5 on the validation.

Please note that changing from Resnet to InceptionV3, and blocking 50 layers, I obtain more than 0.95 of accuracy on both validation and test sets.

Here is the main part of my code:

```py
inc_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet',
                        include_top=False,
                        input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3))

print("number of layers:", len(inc_model.layers)) #175
#Adding custom Layers
x = inc_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
predictions = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(x)

model_ = Model(inputs=inc_model.input, outputs=predictions)

# fine tuning 1
for layer in inc_model.layers[:30]:
        layer.trainable = False
# fine tuning 2
for layer in inc_model.layers:
    if 'bn' in layer.name:
        layer.trainable = False

# compile the model
model_.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9)
                    , loss='categorical_crossentropy'
                    , metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='weights.best.inc.male.resnet.hdf5', 
                               verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

hist = model_.fit_generator(train_generator
                     , validation_data = (x_valid, y_valid)
                      , steps_per_epoch= TRAINING_SAMPLES/BATCH_SIZE
                      , epochs= NUM_EPOCHS
                      , callbacks=[checkpointer]
                      , verbose=1
                    )
```

Can anyone suggest how to find a stable solution that learns something but doesn't overfit?

EDIT:
the output of the training phase is something like that:

```
Epoch 1/20
625/625 [==============================] - 2473s 4s/step - loss: 0.6048 - acc: 0.6691 - val_loss: 8.0590 - val_acc: 0.5000

Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 8.05905, saving model to weights.best.inc.male.resnet.hdf5
Epoch 2/20
625/625 [==============================] - 2432s 4s/step - loss: 0.4445 - acc: 0.7923 - val_loss: 8.0590 - val_acc: 0.5000

Epoch 00002: val_loss did not improve from 8.05905
Epoch 3/20
625/625 [==============================] - 2443s 4s/step - loss: 0.3730 - acc: 0.8407 - val_loss: 8.0590 - val_acc: 0.5000

Epoch 00003: val_loss did not improve from 8.05905
```

and so on.. Every time there's no improvements on the validation

Answer (score 0):

You have many choices but did try [early stopping?](https://keras.io/callbacks/) or you can try to do some [data augmentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), or test with a simpler model.

Comment: I tried early stopping but it doesn't improve. The problem is that only the first epoch of training is effective, because after that one the validation scores never improve. I was already doing data augmentation. Which simpler model can you suggest me?

Comment: @NicolòPomini first, can you post your output here? then did you try changing your learning rate or your optimizer? although it is not guaranteed to work but try VGG16 or VGG19.

Comment: I added the output of the training phase in the question. Up to now I tried with SGD, Adagrad and Adadelta

Comment: Ok, now I see that your training loss keeps decreasing while your validation loss does not change (then this means the network might be overfitting). You can try increasing dropout ratio to 0.7 or block/delete some layers (be careful with this).  Also it seems that using another pre-trained network  solves the problem, right?

Comment: Absurdly I obtain better results setting the dropout ratio to 0.3 and freezing the first 80 layers, plus all the batch normalization layers: with this setup the final accuracy reaches 0.56, which is still very bad.
Yes, using InceptionV3 the model works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

In Resnet, if you are not using the `preprocessing_function` of resnet, try using it as shown below:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(dtype='float32', preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.resnet.preprocess_input)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(dtype='float32', preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.resnet.preprocess_input)
```

Keep everything else the same.